# SQL - How to do something like value.Contains?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

someone can help me, I need to exclude some repeated values, the result is:

[image: this is my result]

There are some rows with null values and in that case I named 'No Informado'.
In line from 26 to 32 there is the same value1 and value2, but value3 is different.

I will need this result,

```
   id                                 | name          | user
   0x00E281759429DD4B807F467F8B2319E3 | PC_XBPOX0112  | llopez   
   0x00F37F5DA2C8854699EFBA30F7102DDD | PC_BSCTY1312  | No Informado
   0x00F53DBE60CFF343942E3893ABA809EB | PC_SVCTY6834  | ntapia
   0x00FDB75C00B8D84E8A1862A56C71A766 | NB_TSCTY06606 | jogonzalez   
   0x010029519191B34BB498E7F9FEAE3E21 | PC_BSCTY3229  | kfuentes
   0x011506756396BC4588E705BFCFA84847 | PC_BSCTY3134  | csepulveda
   0x0120BE537B242C4EB01C4F94E82E64BF | PC_BSCTY1296  | eaviles   
   0x01322ABEC4F19E41B2139291952838EE | PC_VSCTY6535  | vbravo   
   0x0133C6B80B50E44A928AF770510856E3 | PC_FSCTY0084  | mcarreno
   0x01463ECF32DEBD41943330EC7C1822D4 | PC_BSCTY3220  | fegonzalez
   0x01610C718C04264A8349FAEA6676363F | PC-FSCTY0543  | fcastro
```

someone can help me?
Forward thanks!

Comment: What does `something like` mean? Return the latest name per ID or return the maximum name and date per ID? The result will be the same *only* for this sample. If the last value was eg name0 the results would be different

Comment: @HazarathChillara there are no duplicate values here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is the **WITH TIES** clause in concert with **Row_Number()**

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 With Ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by Date Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
id  name    date
1   name1   2018-01-01
2   name2   2018-01-01
3   name5   2018-02-01
```

Comment: There is some way to include null values? THANKS @John Cappelletti !

Comment: @DibuEscobedo Perhaps edit your sample and desired results.  Having a little trouble with the visual.

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti I resolved it with that sentence!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  Id
      , MAX(name) AS Name
      , MAX([date]) AS [date]
FROM  TableName 
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: My first thought as well, but max(Name) is risky.  What if name4 was Zebra ?

Comment: MAX() doesn't work, because there are many names without a number.